# Modbus Protocol - MJK Device - Get Device ID ( Slave ID )

Tags: c#, modbus-tcp

I need to read register values of difference device via TCP Listeners.

To get the values of register we need to request to device with device ID, in below code 0xF7 is hard coded passed.

Now we have more than 500 devices which will connect to our port, so Is there any way to get device ID ( slaveID )  when they connect to our TCP Port?

```
   Int32 port = int.Parse(TCPPort);
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(TCPHost);
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
                server.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                Console.WriteLine();

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                string loggerTime = RequestTime(client, stream);
                } ...

         


static string RequestTime(TcpClient client, NetworkStream stream)
        {
            // 0xF7 is hard coded here, this needs to find
            byte[] sendData = { 0xF7, 0x03, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x00, 0x02, 0xE1, 0x5B }; 

            stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);

            Byte[] data = new Byte[9];

            try
            {
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                if (ValidateCRC(data, data.Length) && bytes != 0)
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[] { data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6] };
                    buf.SwapBytes(0, 1);
                    buf.SwapBytes(2, 3);
                    Array.Reverse(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    string hexValue = ConvertBytesToHexa(buf);

                    int secondsAfterEpoch = Int32.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                    DateTime loggerTime = epoch.AddSeconds(secondsAfterEpoch);
                    Console.WriteLine("Logger UTC Time: {0}", loggerTime.ToUniversalTime());
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    return loggerTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Response CRC is not matched for UTC Time");
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you say "TCP Listeners" do you mean a standard Modbus TCP server? (it looks like you may be using a reverse setup with the server connecting to the client). The [Modbus TCP spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf) really only discusses using the remote IP to identify the client (along with a single byte 'Unit Identifier'). I guess you could look at the [MODBUS Security Protocol](https://www.modbus.org/docs/MB-TCP-Security-v21_2018-07-24.pdf) and use certificates to identify your clients (but that relies upon your devices supporting this).

Comment: @Brits Thank you for  your valuable inputs, I was totally misunderstood the concept.

{ 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x02, 0x44, 0x0C };

here 0x01  was model ID, (247)

0x00, 0x18 = 24  this is register number (REG#),  by requesting this we are able to receive On-Chip Serial Number, that is device ID for us.